# Regular expression to remove lines with special characters

Tags: regex

```
        <a class='jdr' href='javascript:void(0);' onClick="return openDiv('jrtp');"></a>            
        <span class="jcn">
            <a href="http://example.com/Ahmedabad/Aptech-N-Power-Hardware-Networking-&lt;near&gt;-Toll-Naka-Opp-Kakadia-Hospital-Below-Sankalp-Reataurant-Bapu-Nagar/079PXX79-XX79-110420173655-D4K6_QWhtZWRhYmFkIENDTkEgVHJhaW5pbmcgSW5zdGl0dXRlcw==_BZDET" title='Aptech N Power Hardware & Networking' >Aptech N Power Hardware & Networkin...</a>
        </span>         

            <section class="jrat">
                <a rel="nofollow" href="http://example.com/Ahmedabad/Aptech-N-Power-Hardware-Networking-&lt;near&gt;-Toll-Naka-Opp-Kakadia-Hospital-Below-Sankalp-Reataurant-Bapu-Nagar/079PXX79-XX79-110420173655-D4K6_QWhtZWRhYmFkIENDTkEgVHJhaW5pbmcgSW5zdGl0dXRlcw==_BZDET#rvw"><span class='s10'></span><span class='s10'></span><span class='s10'></span><span class='s10'></span><span class='s0'></span></a> 
                                        <a class="jrt" href="http://example.com/Ahmedabad/Aptech-N-Power-Hardware-Networking-&lt;near&gt;-Toll-Naka-Opp-Kakadia-Hospital-Below-Sankalp-Reataurant-Bapu-Nagar/079PXX79-XX79-110420173655-D4K6_QWhtZWRhYmFkIENDTkEgVHJhaW5pbmcgSW5zdGl0dXRlcw==_BZDET#rvw">2 ratings</a>
                    <span class="jrt"> |</span>
                                    <a class="rate_this" onclick="_ct('ratethis','lspg');"  href="http://example.com/Ahmedabad/Aptech-N-Power-Hardware-Networking-&lt;near&gt;-Toll-Naka-Opp-Kakadia-Hospital-Below-Sankalp-Reataurant-Bapu-Nagar/079PXX79-XX79-110420173655-D4K6_QWhtZWRhYmFkIENDTkEgVHJhaW5pbmcgSW5zdGl0dXRlcw==_BZDET/writereview">Rate this</a>
            </section>                      
        <section class="jcar">
            <section class="jbc">
                                        <a href="http://example.com/Ahmedabad/Aptech-N-Power-Hardware-Networking-&lt;near&gt;-Toll-Naka-Opp-Kakadia-Hospital-Below-Sankalp-Reataurant-Bapu-Nagar/079PXX79-XX79-110420173655-D4K6_QWhtZWRhYmFkIENDTkEgVHJhaW5pbmcgSW5zdGl0dXRlcw==_BZDET">
                        <img width="83" height="56" border="0" src="http://images.jdmagicbox.com/upload_test/ahmedabad/b4/079pxx79.xx79.110420172948.d4b4/logo/faf3f2409ed7993aaa70f848ab0bb6fb_t.jpg" class="Clogo" />
                    </a>
                                        <!-- <span class="noLogo"></span> -->
                                                        <section class="jrcl">
                    <p>
                        **A/35, Lakhani Chamber, Toll Naka, Opp Kakadia Hospital, Below Sankalp Reataurant, Bapu Nagar, Ahmedabad - 380024**                                                                |<a href="http://example.com/Ahmedabad/Aptech-N-Power-Hardware-Networking-&lt;near&gt;-Toll-Naka-Opp-Kakadia-Hospital-Below-Sankalp-Reataurant-Bapu-Nagar/079PXX79-XX79-110420173655-D4K6_QWhtZWRhYmFkIENDTkEgVHJhaW5pbmcgSW5zdGl0dXRlcw==_BZDET/map"> View Map</a><br>
                                                    </p>
```

From the above XML data I want to extract the following---
A/35, Lakhani Chamber, Toll Naka, Opp Kakadia Hospital, Below Sankalp Reataurant, Bapu Nagar, Ahmedabad - 380024

**I need help in creating a regular expression to find and remove all lines containing special characters.
I am using the following regex ----
/(\<.+?>)/g
Please help.Thanks**

Comment: What lines are you talking about ? Where is your regex in your code ?

Comment: What is special character for you ?

Comment: Well what i meant was--Regular expression that matches all the strings in the given html

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Do you want to extract the `same address` as given above always or your address can vary based on different documents and you want generalised regex to extract the address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
/(?<=\*{2})([^<>]*?)(?=\*{2})/g
```

it matches all content between the `**`.

Comment: @buk ha ha, i think that was funny. i think ** was  not in the original text. I think the op tried to make it bold and thats why `**` came there

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove lines which are HTML tags, so try this:

```
/^<.*>\n/g
```

Comment: what should this do? i think it's useless